# Exchange 2019 Management Shell: Server Identity Object Couldn't be found in DC

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

When I want to run a Command Such as:

```
Set-OutlookProvider -Identity "MyExchangeServer" -CertPrincipalName...
```

in Exchange Management Shell,  It gives this error:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object '' MyExchangeServer '' couldn't be found on 'MyDC1.MyDomain.local'.
```

I've tested other commands which take -Identity as an Argument and the same error is being printed again!

Comment: Do you see any servers listed if you run `Get-ExchangeServer -Domain mydomain.local`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, it shows my only exchange server. and i've used this name as identity for those commands. also i've executed exchange management shell as domain administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-outlookprovider?view=exchange-ps  Get-OutlookProvider command,

-Identity

The Identity parameter specifies the ADIDParameter value of the MAPI protocol that you want to view. Typical values are:

EXCH
EXPR
WEB

It does not reflect the Exchange Server name. It reflects the configurable settings of Autodiscovery object which is forest-wide. You may see those protocol names for e.g. in Test Autodiscover results in Outlook

So I think you should supply similar values for Set-OutlookProvider Identity parameter.